# Get first N elements of std::list?

Tags: c++, visual-c++-2010, stdlist

What is the correct and safe way to get a new list that is the first N elements of a std::list or the entire list if N >= the list size (and handles N = 0 as well)?

**Update**

In fact I don't necessarily need a new list, I just want to operate on the subset of the list in subsequent code.  I assume creating a new list is a reasonable way to do this (note list size will typically be under 50).

Comment: Chances are you *don't* want to use `std::list` for either the input *or* the result. In most cases, `std::vector` will make life a lot simpler. Most algorithms work on a defined range, which will allow you to operate on the correct subset without copying at all.

Comment: @JerryCoffin I need to sort the list before taking the subset, does that affect the decision to use a vector?

Comment: Yes -- it makes vector an even better choice. If you just want the N largest (or smallest) items, you can use `std::nth_element` to get them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
std::list<int> a;
size_t n = 13;
auto end = std::next(a.begin(), std::min(n, a.size()));
```

Make a new list containing the first n elements of the first list:

```
std::list<int> b(a.begin(), end);
```

Or populate an existing list:

```
std::list<int> b;
std::copy(a.begin(), end, std::back_inserter(b));
```

Comment: I looked and I don't think `std::advance` takes care of going past the end. At least the standard just leaves it at advancing the iterator. It doesn't mention checking for that.

Comment: Why can't you simply do `a.begin() + n`?

Comment: @0x499602D2, It's a bidirectional iterator. `std::next` works regardless.

Comment: Since OP talks of a "new list" it might make more sense to construct `b` using the two iterator constructor.

Comment: Why did you break your code by replacing `std::next`, which works on list iterators, with `operator+`, which does not?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley For fun. Fixed.

Answer (score 6):

```
template<typename T>
std::list<T> first_n(const std::list<T> &in, std::size_t n) {
    return std::list<T> out{in.begin(),
      std::next(in.begin(), std::min(in.size(), n))};
}
```

Comment: In order to "return" a list I've always passed the empty list in as a parameter to the function.  Does the way you're doing it here have cost implications that a return parameter doesn't? As a C# programmer I'd prefer this way but most of what I have read advises against returning containers via a return statement.

Comment: @User see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/753312/returning-large-objects-in-functions - in all modern compilers returning the container will be just as efficient as taking an out-parameter.

Answer (score 4):

```
// list<int> input;
list<int> output;
for (list<int>::const_iterator i = input.begin(); i != input.end() && N > 0; ++i, --N)
    output.push_back(*i);
```

Comment: I guess nobody else agrees that iterating the list twice when you can easily avoid it like this is silly pessimization.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: what do you mean? Are you saying this a better answer than the others or not as good? Do the other answers result in the list being iterated over twice?

Comment: @User: Yes, I am saying that this answer is probably more efficient, though perhaps not by much.  The other answers make use of `std::next` to find the end iterator with which to initialize the second list.  For a container like `std::vector` or `std::deque`, that would be a cheap operation, because they have random access iterators.  But for `std::list`, since it has bi-directional iterators, it requires iterating through each item in the list up to N.  Then when you initialize the second list, you need to iterate again.

Answer (score 0):

In your question noticed saying

> In fact I don't necessarily need a new list, I just want to operate on
> the subset of the list in subsequent code

Form C++17 one can use `std::for_each_n`

For example lets square the first N (4) numbers in the list.

**Example 1 : Modify in place :**

```
    std::list<int> nums{ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 };

    //MAKE NOTE OF SENDING ARGUMENT AS A REFERENCE (int& num)
    std::for_each_n(nums.begin(), 4, [](int& num) { num = num * num; });

    //PRINT
    for (auto n : nums)
        std::cout << n << "  ";
```

**Example 2 : Modify and put them in a different list :**

```
    std::list<int> nums2{ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 };
    std::list<int> newNums;

    //MAKE NOTE OF CAPTURE [&}, newNums EXPOSED INSIDE LAMBDA.
    std::for_each_n(nums2.begin(), 4, [&](int num) {newNums.push_back(num * num); });
    
    //PRINT
    for (auto n : newNums)
        std::cout << n << "  ";
```

Also there is an overload available to specify execution policy, Need to include "execution" header. So the below code executes with parallel execution policy, useful for parallel processing lists huge in size.

```
std::for_each_n(std::execution::par,nums.begin(), 4, [](int& num) { num = num * num; });
```