# Return a large std::vector from a function

Tags: c++

In C++ 11, if I have a function that returns a `std::vector<int>` with a very large number of elements, does this return a deep or shallow copy of the vector which was originally created?

E.g.

```
std::vector<int> GetVec()
{
    std::vector<int> bar(1000000);
    // Fill in bar with numbers
    return bar;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> foo = GetVec();
    return 0;
}
```

Will `foo` be a deep copy of the entire contents of `bar`, or will it just be a reference to `bar`?

My understanding is the C++ functions return copies, so in this case, how should I avoid having the make a costly copy of `bar` inside this function? I know that the elements of a `std::vector` are created on the heap, so I'm wondering if copying `bar` in the function creates a deep or shallow copy.

One way would be to pass `foo` as an argument:

```
void GetVec(std::vector<int>& bar)
{
    bar.resize(1000000);
    // Fill in bar with numbers
};
```

Another way would be to return by reference:

```
std::vector<int>& GetVec()
{
    std::vector<int> bar(1000000);
    // Fill in bar with numbers
    return bar;
};
```

But what's the best practice?

Comment: are you compiling this with C++11?

Comment: Your last snippet is not correct. You cannot return a reference to a temporary object.

Comment: Search on here for "NRVO"

Comment: Just copy by value. The returning will be optimized. Look up: Return value optimization (RVO), copy elision and move semantics.

Comment: For some additional information, see this duplicate as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/753312/returning-large-objects-in-functions

Comment: @merlin2011 the elements are created on the heap even if you didn't use 'new' explicitly to instantiate the vector container

Comment: @MarcoA., I thought he was referring to the container object itself. I think I misread the question.