# Problem with returning large struct in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-c++, struct

This might seem obsolete, but I am working on a program that is supposed to work on Windows XP 32bit - we are still using a couple of those because of old EEG recorder that is incompatible with anything else. I use QT Creator 4.14.1 and vc2012 compiler for 32bit and MinGW for 64bit (which does not produce this problem).

I am writing a C++ code for reading EEG data files (and then exporting them in another format). Everything works fine with smaller files, but when the files got bigger then hour and something (each page has 10 seconds with 1 kHz sampling rate), problem occurs.

Following code is supposed to read data from file - for reproducibility I have reduced it to storing zeroes - and return struct consisting of 1) data itself (vector of vectors) and 2) pages info (vector of custom type with two numbers in it).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct SignalPage
{
    unsigned short filling;
    long time;
};

struct Spages
{
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> esignals;
    std::vector<SignalPage> pages;
};


Spages read_signal_pages(int channels_used, int num_pages, int save_buffer_size)
{

    std::vector<std::vector<double>> esignals(channels_used, std::vector<double>());

    for(int ch = 0; ch < channels_used; ch++){
        esignals[ch].reserve(save_buffer_size * (num_pages+1));
    }

    std::vector<SignalPage> pages;
    pages.reserve(num_pages);

    for(int j = 0; j < num_pages; j++){
        SignalPage page;
        page.filling = 0;
        page.time = 0;
        pages.push_back(page);

        for (int i = 0; i < channels_used; i++){
            std::vector<short> b(save_buffer_size,0); // in original code is short later transformed in double
            int start_index = j * save_buffer_size;
            esignals[i].insert(esignals[i].begin() + start_index, b.begin(), b.end());
        }

    }

    Spages spages;
    spages.pages = pages;
    spages.esignals = esignals;
    std::cout << "Here!" << std::endl;
    return spages;
}




int main()
{
    Spages spages = read_signal_pages(19,450,10000); // 655 for release, 450 for debug, 64bit manages e.g. 9000
    std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Error occurs on the return statement, at first I thought maybe the copy elision does not work properly, so I tested it using this: [Returning Large Objects in Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/753312/returning-large-objects-in-functions) and it worked fine.

If I am counting it right, the size of esignals (actual data) is nowhere near the 4 GB limit: e.g. 450 pages = 450 * 10000 * 19 * 8 = 684 MB.

Full error stack:

```
1  RaiseException                                                                                                                                                                                    KERNELBASE          0x74ffd902 
2  CxxThrowException                                                                                                                                                                                 MSVCR120D           0x6f690b86 
3  operator new                                                                                                                                                                                      MSVCR120D           0x6f69c2a1 
4  std::_Allocate<double>                                                                                                                                                                            xmemory0       28   0xea3bc0   
5  std::allocator<double>::allocate                                                                                                                                                                  xmemory0       578  0xea90f9   
6  std::_Wrap_alloc<std::allocator<double>>::allocate                                                                                                                                                xmemory0       848  0xeaefda   
7  std::vector<double>::_Buy                                                                                                                                                                         vector         1557 0xeacb4f   
8  std::vector<double>::vector<double>                                                                                                                                                               vector         722  0xea7f41   
9  std::allocator<std::vector<double,std::allocator<double>>>::construct                                                                                                                             xmemory0       593  0xea7cd3   
10 std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<std::vector<double,std::allocator<double>>>>::construct<std::vector<double,std::allocator<double>>,std::vector<double,std::allocator<double>> const &>       xmemory0       724  0xea86fc   
11 std::_Wrap_alloc<std::allocator<std::vector<double,std::allocator<double>>>>::construct<std::vector<double,std::allocator<double>>,std::vector<double,std::allocator<double>> const &>            xmemory0       872  0xea5d78   
12 std::_Uninit_copy<std::vector<double> const *,std::vector<double> *,std::allocator<std::vector<double>>>                                                                                          xmemory        378  0xea70aa   
13 std::_Uninit_copy<std::vector<double> const *,std::vector<double> *,std::_Wrap_alloc<std::allocator<std::vector<double>>>>                                                                        xmemory        416  0xea6928   
14 std::_Uninitialized_copy<std::_Vector_const_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<std::vector<double>>>>,std::vector<double> *,std::_Wrap_alloc<std::allocator<std::vector<double,std::all xmemory        427  0xeaed05   
15 std::vector<std::vector<double>>::_Ucopy<std::_Vector_const_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<std::vector<double>>>>>                                                                  vector         1640 0xead2a0   
16 std::vector<std::vector<double>>::vector<std::vector<double>>                                                                                                                                     vector         725  0xeb06f3   
17 Spages::Spages                                                                                                                                                                                    Bad_alloc_test      0xeaa4e9   
18 read_signal_pages                                                                                                                                                                                 main.cpp       47   0xeb3543   
19 main                                                                                                                                                                                              main.cpp       56   0xeb3694   
20 __tmainCRTStartup                                                                                                                                                                                 crtexe.c       626  0xeb1719   
21 mainCRTStartup                                                                                                                                                                                    crtexe.c       466  0xeb185d   
22 BaseThreadInitThunk                                                                                                                                                                               KERNEL32            0x7690fcc9 
23 RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath                                                                                                                                                                 ntdll_76f00000      0x76f67b1e 
24 RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath
```

I tried using tuple, since I am worried that the source of the problem is returning two variables from one function, but I guess it is basically the same.

Can it be a problem with move constructor (meaning that my custom struct does not have any)? Or is there anything wrong with memory allocation I do?

I was thinking about going through the file twice - once for data and once for page info, but it seemed redundant. Or use passing by reference - but I thought that the compiler should manage the overhead with passing by value.

If this is some intrinsic flaw in old compiler I will just have to move to 64bit version.

Comment: Do you need full double precision for the values? Would using single-precision `float` be enough? That will save you 50% for that data. Otherwise, do you need to read *all* data and keep it in memory? Could you read smaller sections  and work on that instead?

Comment: You're not using move-semantics anywhere here. So, there's potentially a lot of copies happening. I don't think the compiler is required to elide everything. You have not specified whether your program outputs `Here!` before crashing. Does it?

Comment: `spages.esignals = esignals;` for instance is a full copy. Store the values directly in `spages.esignals`, that immediately saves you 684 MB. With all the copies going around, you easily exceed 2GB.

Comment: There is a lot of pointless copying going on there. When you want a vector with several identical elements, do it in initialization instead of with a manual loop. (And you need to consider the amount of *contiguous* memory available.)

Comment: @paddy It does output "Here!" and then it crashes on the return statement.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I will check, but I am afraid that I need double. And I have already been thinking about rewriting the code that it will read just chunk of the original data in the buffer and write it in the output file chunk by chunk.

Comment: Looks like the compiler does not support [NRVO](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision), which means the `return` statement in the end of `read_signal_pages` creates a copy of `spages`. This is in addition to copies being created during assignment to `spages` members, as was pointed out in the comments above. You can try passing a reference to (an externally constructed) `Spages` object as an argument to `read_signal_pages` and operate on that object in the function instead of returning it.

Comment: BTW, it is possible that NRVO is disabled because you're compiling in debug mode.

Comment: This probably wouldn't be an issue at all if using C++ best-practices, such as making `read_signal_pages` a class method, and/or using RAII paradigm.